# PHP - Does passing each input request to a variable makes it slower and consumes more bytes?

Tags: php, laravel

Which of this two is better and more accurate and optimized

Option A or Option B?

please tell me which is wrong, I'm confused :(

Thanks!

Option A

```
class nameMyController extends Controller {

protected $locationId = 0;
protected $roomId = 0;
protected $participants = 0;
protected $startDate = null;
protected $endDate = null;
protected $request;

public function abc(Request $request) {
        $requestLocation = $request->input('office_site');
        $requestRoom = $request->input('rooms');
        $requestParticipants = $request->input('participants');
        $requestStartDate = $request->input('start_date');
        $requestEndDate = $request->input('end_date');

        $this->request = $request->all();

        if ($requestLocation != '') $this->locationId = $requestLocation;
        if ($requestRoom != '') $this->roomId = $requestRoom;
        if ($requestParticipants != '') $this->participants = $requestParticipants[0];
        if ($requestStartDate != '') $this->startDate = Carbon::parse($requestStartDate)->format(config('constants.DB_DATE_FORMAT'));
        if ($requestEndDate != '') $this->endDate = Carbon::parse($requestEndDate)->format(config('constants.DB_DATE_FORMAT'));

}

}
```

Or this Option B,

```
class nameMyController extends Controller {

protected $locationId = 0;
protected $roomId = 0;
protected $participants = 0;
protected $startDate = null;
protected $endDate = null;
protected $request;

public function abc(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request->all();

        if ($request->input('office_site') != '') $this->locationId = $request->input('office_site');
        if ($request->input('rooms') != '') $this->roomId = $request->input('rooms');
        if ($request->input('participants') != '') $this->participants = $request->input('participants')[0];
        if ($request->input('start_date') != '') $this->startDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('start_date'))->format(config('constants.DB_DATE_FORMAT'));
        if ($request->input('end_date') != '') $this->endDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('end_date'))->format(config('constants.DB_DATE_FORMAT'));

}
}
```

I want to know which works faster, better, more optimized and reusable.
And does passing to value to object property okay than passing as a parameter to a function inside a class/object?

Comment: It is exactly the same, given that the first one works.

Answer (score 1):

As PHP uses Copy-On-Write you would notice any difference between two(performance-wise), especially compared to the cost of kernel booting. Keep calm and use profiler to measure your performance. In enterprise development you wouldn't(and you really shouldn't) think about such things until you start to notice performance drawdowns on your actions.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a good practice to create variable for a value that will be used only once?**

It's strongly depends on context.
Probably it is if in the future you will need to somehow modify this value in the middle or if this will increase readability of your code.

From the perspective of a performance I think that underneath the hood it will produce same result with a same speed, but this is just my opinion, not proved by any tests.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much you be re-using those variable(like $requestLocation), As far as reusability is concerned option A is better plus [Storing a PHP integer takes 68 bytes of memory](http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2008/03/did_you_know_that_each_integer.html), This is a small enough amount, that I think I'd rather worry about processing time than memory space.